# Non-vanishing of L-series of modular forms (easy case?)

Tags: modular-forms

If f is a weight 2 cuspidal newform, then it is common for L(f,1) to vanish.  Indeed, the sign of the functional equation of f can force such vanishing.  However, if f has weight k>2, then there is no a priori reason why L(f,1) will vanish.

My question: are there known examples where L(f,1)=0 for a newform f of weight strictly greater than 2 or is there some (easy?) reason such examples shouldn't exist?

Comment: How are you normalizing the functional equation?  Is $s=1$ meant to be on the critical line?

Comment: My normalization of the $L$-series is $L(f,s) = \sum_n a_n n^{-s}$ where $f=\sum a_n q^n$, and so $1$ is not on the critical line if $k>2$.

Comment: Well then this resolves your question, because the Grand Riemann Hypothesis for automorphic $L$-functions says that all the zeroes must occur on the critical line. However, there is no proof of this fact: even zero-free regions for automorphic forms do not eliminate the case of a Siegel zero (if $f$ is self-dual).

It is much more common to write the normalisation as $L(s,f) = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1}{a_f(n) n^{-s}}$, where $f(z) = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1}{a_f(n) n^{(k - 1)/2} e(nz)}$, as this then ensures that $L(s,f)$ has critical line $\Re(s) = 1/2$.

Comment: @Peter: Actually Hoffstein and Ramakrishnan proved that for GL(2) cusp forms $L(s,f)$ has no Siegel zeros. See http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/content/1995/6/279.extract

Comment: Why are Siegel zeros relevant here?  Aren't these zeroes close to the center of critical strip?  Even for k=3, s=1 is pretty from the center.

Comment: Siegel zeros are very close to the edge of the critical strip, i.e. very far from the center. In some sense they are the worst (potential) violations of GRH.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your normalization, $L(s,f)$ is defined as an Euler product for $\Re(s)>\frac{k+1}{2}$, so $L(s,f)$ is non-zero in that right-half plane. Now Jacquet–Shalika [MR0432596](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=432596) showed that that non-zero region extends to the line $\Re(s)=\frac{k+1}{2}$ (for $\mathrm{GL}(n)$, in fact) (this is analogous to the proof of non-vanishing on the line $s=1$ for $\zeta(s)$). Furthermore, $L(s,f)$ satisfies a functional equation $\Lambda(s,f)=i^k\Lambda(k-s,W_Nf)$ where $N$ is the level of $f$, $W_N$ is the Atkin-Lehner operator, so $W_Nf$ is also weight $k$ and level $N$, and $\Lambda(s,f)=N^{s/2}(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)L(s,f)$. So, $s=\frac{k}{2}$ is the central point (which is indeed $\neq1$ if $k>2$) (stuff like Beilinson–Deligne–Bloch–Kato basically says that vanishing away from the central point should be easier to understand). Now the values of $L(s,f)$ at $0\lt s\leq\frac{k-1}{2}$ are related to values of a possibly different modular form ($W_Nf$) at $k-s$, i.e. in the non-vanishing range $\Re(s)\geq\frac{k+1}{2}$. The only complicating part of this relation is the Gamma factors, but at these $s$, both $s$ and $k-s$ are $>0$, so they are not poles of $\Gamma(s)$. Hence, $L(s,f)\neq0$ at all positive $s$ except possibly in the strip $\frac{k-1}{2}\lt\Re(s)\lt\frac{k+1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The sign of the functional equation of a self-dual cusp form (regardless its weight) can be changed easily by twisting the form with a quadratic character. In particular, the $L$-function of a self-dual cusp form (of any weight) often vanishes at the center. I don't think there is anything special about weight 2. See Theorem 7.6 in Iwaniec: Topics in classical automorphic forms.

Comment: Experimental evidence shows that when the sign is $+1$, vanishing is much more common for weight $2$ than for other weights; I think one or two examples are known for weight $4$, and none for weight $\geq 6$.  Perhaps William Stein can confirm this?

Comment: David, very interesting! In my comment I only cared about the sign of the functional equation.

Comment: Stein has a paper (link below] where they give data for some weight 4 and 6 vanishings of small level. I thought the conjecture was "finitely many" for weight 6 and infinitely for weight 4, though maybe that is for twists. My recollection is that there is no known example beyond elliptic curves that has a triple vanishing.
http://www.neil-dummigan.staff.shef.ac.uk/dsw_13.dvi


Comment: There is another paper http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/~watkins/papers/heur.pdf and it gives 3 examples of weight 8 forms that vanish (CM) doubly in Table 3 page 23 and Table 5 next page, and says no triple zeros are known in this case.